# Pass data to next request in for loop

Tags: javascript, angular, ajax, for-loop, file-upload

I have a image upload Request with a `param`. I want to send response of 1st request to all next requests inside for loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
  this.http.uploadImages(e.target.files[i], 'UploadImage', this.postId).subscribe((res:any)=>{
    if(res.status == true){
      this.postId = res.data.post_id; // i want to pass this postId to All other Requests. 
      this.userImages.push({ img: res.data });
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: You should not make any other request inside the subscribe of the first request. Just get the promise and await it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet will perform every upload in series, updating the `this.postId` value each time. Using arrow functions `this` context is preserved.

(If your `this.http.uploadImages` method already returns a promise you don't need to instantiate a new one)

```js
const upload = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http
                .uploadImages(e.target.files[i], 'UploadImage', this.postId)
                .subscribe((res: any) => {
                    if (res.status) {
                        this.postId = res.data.post_id;
                        this.userImages.push({img: res.data});

                        resolve();
                    } else {
                        reject();
                    }
                });
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: It Worked. Now I have One more Question. this is basically Ionic application. and I am Using `FileTransfer` plugin for Mobile App. i want to achieve same for `FileTransfer` Plugin.  
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib please submit a new question for that so that others can also participate.

Comment: have made new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68636130/5909026

Answer (score -2):

Create new variable before for-loop and store postId from response. Than in request check this variable. If empty - skip, if not - send