# How To Send Array Data One By One To API in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I have data like this

> [292929282,372828272,9822922,82729292]

Now I want to send one by one value to API to get response of that specific value
Here what I have tried. Please tell me what is wrong, because I am not getting any data in response.

```
for (let i = 0; i < getBrandNameById2.length; i++) {
      fetch('URL', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
        body:
          JSON.stringify({
            brandid: getBrandNameById2[i],
          }),
      })
```

Comment: You can make a promise for each request and when 1st request gets complete then send 2nd request.

Comment: check this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68634092/5909026